# Inserting Data to database using Repository in mvc4? unable to insert the multiple data?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have two Entities **billing** and **BillingDetail**
in **billing** I am adding more than one time and after that I am adding data to **BillingDetail**
 finally I am Saving the Database. but when i checked database in **billing** table, it was containg only last data(only one row that was last updated) 
How I supposed to solve this problem?

```
            foreach ()
            {

                billingRepository.Insert(billModel);

            }
            billingDetailRepository.Insert(billDetailModel);

            dbContext.Save();
```

Comment: what error are u getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error, billingRepository.Insert(billModel) here i am inserting data two/three times but only last inserted data is saving in database rest is not saving

Answer (score 0):

When an entity is inserted is will be in attached state. Therefor Entity Framework will know it already exists in the context an not insert it again.

You can detach the entity and then insert it again to have it multiple times. But beware, after an insert PK fields are auto mapped to the entity.

Comment: Thank you @stefchri, but how to do that one, i new to EntityFramework